# JQuery UI: draggable item loses ability to drag/drop after clone-drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some divs that the user can move to a target-div. If they are dropped, a new div will be appended there. But now the user should be able to do it again and again. But after the clone was dropped (anywhere - not only in the droppable) the original item loses the ability to drop. How can I change it that users can move an original-item many times to the target-div?

The following code shows a script-example which works exakt 1 time. After one drop the first part doesn't work any more. I tried to add it this function again after dropping without success.

```
   $('.move-me').draggable({
     revert: "invalid",
     helper: "clone"
   });

   $('#target').droppable({
     accept: '.move-me',
     drop: function (event, ui) {
       $(this).append('<div>You dropped an element here</div>');
     }
   });
```

Comment: `$('#target').droppable({` You're not cloning this ID, are you? You can only have **ONE** element per ID.

Comment: I use the helper-clone only that the '.move-me'-element is placed the whole time at the starting place and the droppable function can be used. If the "clone" is dropped, it disappears. A new div is appended without any ID or any reference to the '.move-me'-element.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your droppable code. Please check once.

```
$('.move-me').draggable({
     revert: "invalid",
     helper: "clone",
    cursor : "move",
   });

   $('#target').droppable({
     accept: '.move-me',
     drop: function (event, ui) {
// Make sure you are cloning your draggable and use that div to modify as per your requirement
    var html = $(ui.draggable).clone(true);
     ui.draggable.draggable('enable');
       $(this).append('<div>You dropped an element here</div>');
     }
   });
```

Glad if it works.

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't change anything. Still can't move the element again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I sorted this issue by updating css rule. I was dropping the element to a div which had higher z-index than the dropped item. I just added a class and set z-index value greater than that of drop container. This solved my issue.

Hope this might help if any of the above answers did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but it seems that if you call draggable() again it must be outside the document ready function. I moved outside the ready function when I called it again and it worked like a charm.